# C#: Sorting a dictionary in which the keys are List<object>

Tags: c#, list, linq, sorting, dictionary

Hello to everyone reading this! Tl;dr I have a `Dictionary<string, List<object>>` called
"table" with the following keys:

```
"id" being int,
"date" being Datetime,
"name", "entry1", "entry2", "entry3" being strings.
```

And all the values to the keys in the `List<object>` list. I want to order the dictionary by the `name` field, the names being like "John Doe". I tried using .OrderBy() and it would either throw exceptions or order just that key and not the whole dictionary. Ex: `var result = table.Orderby(pairs => pairs.Value[2]);` would throw an exception because the object is not a string.
How can this be done? Thank you!

Edit:
The table is used to use the values in an Excel file:

```
           foreach (var key in table.Keys)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < max; i++)
                {
                    switch (key)
                    {
                        case "id":
                            worksheet.Cells[i + 1, j].Value = ConversionWrapper<int>((int)table[key][i]);
                            break;
                        case "date":
                            worksheet.Cells[i + 1, j].Value = ConversionWrapper<string>((DateTime)table[key][i]);
                            break;
                        case "name":
                        case "entry1":
                        case "entry2":
                        case "entry3":
                        case "entry4":
                            worksheet.Cells[i + 1, j].Value = ConversionWrapper<string>((string)table[key][i]);
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                }

                ++j;
            }

       private static T ConversionWrapper<T>(object elem)
        {
            switch (elem)
            {
                case int:
                case string:
                    return (T)elem;
                case DateTime:
                    return (T)(object)((DateTime)elem).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                default:
                    throw new ArgumentException();
            }
        }

Method to extract the values:

        private static Dictionary<string, List<object>> GetAllElementsLM(SqlConnection conn)
        {
            string query;
            string[] columns = { "id", "date", "name", "entry1", "entry2", "entry3", "entry4" };
            var dic = new Dictionary<string, List<object>>();

            conn.Open();

            foreach (var elem in columns)
            {
                dic.Add(elem, new List<object>());

                query = $@"SELECT {elem} FROM ""feedback""";

                using (var command = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
                {
                    using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            dic[elem].Add(reader.GetValue(0));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            conn.Close();

            return dic;
        }
```

Comment: "_I have a `Dictionary<string, List<object>>` called "table" with the following keys_" That's impossible considering `int` and `DateTime` do not derive from `string`.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay the keys are string, I was reffering to what I convert the object values to

Comment: You shouldn't need to sort a Dictionary. If you do, then a Dictionary is not the correct data structure to be using. Dictionaries are designed for key/value lookup

Comment: Do you want a dictionary that is ordered? Or are you trying to project the dictionary into a _new_ ordered data structure?

Comment: @mjwills I don't "want" a dictionary. The values are extracted from an SQL table and I just found that a dictionary would seem appropriate. I want all the 7 entries (id, date, name etc) to be "linked", whatever the data type I need to use.

Comment: @KuranKaname: If you mean by 7 entries, a SQL Table row then a class would be more suitable. And you store that class in a list. At that time you can sort your list based on the 'name' requirement.

Comment: @RvdK Thanks for the respons that's what I ended up doing.

Comment: You will only have one "name" item in your dictionary with a List<object> as the value.  You could sort that List<object> with table["name"].Value.Cast<string>.Sort()  but it will not sort the other dictionary entries.  You should rethink your design.  Make a class that has properties for  int  id, DateTime date, string name, string entry1...  Then make a List<yourClass>.  In your GetAllElements,  create an instance of yourClass, assign all the properties ->  id, date, name, etc.  Then add that instance to your List.  Then you can sort the list  myList.Orderby( item -> item.name)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using a `List` of my structure:

Entries structure:

```
readonly struct Entries
    {
        public int Id { get; }
        public DateTime Date { get; }
        public string Name { get; }
        public string Entry1 { get; }
        public string Entry2 { get; }
        public string Entry3 { get; }
        public string Entry4 { get; }

        public Entries(int id, DateTime date, string name, string entry1, string entry2, string entry3, string entry4) =>
                (Id, Date, Name, Entry1, Entry2, Entry3, Entry4) = (id, date, name, entry1, entry2, entry3, entry4);
    }
```

Method to get the number of elements:

```
        private static int GetMaxNumber(SqlConnection conn)
        {
            int i = 0;
            string query;

            conn.Open();

            query = $@"SELECT id FROM ""feedback""";

            using (var command = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
            {
                using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        ++i;
                    }
                }
            }

            conn.Close();

            return i;
        }
```

Getting the elements:

```
        private static IEnumerable<Entries> GetAllElementsClass(SqlConnection conn)
        {
            string query;
            List<int> id;
            List<DateTime> date;
            List<string> name, entry1, entry2, entry3, entry4;
            int max = GetMaxNumber(conn);

            conn.Open();

            query = $@"SELECT id FROM ""feedback""";

            id = new List<int>();

            using (var command = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
            {
                using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        id.Add((int)reader.GetValue(0));
                    }
                }
            }

            query = $@"SELECT date FROM ""feedback""";

            date = new List<DateTime>();

            using (var command = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
            {
                using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        date.Add((DateTime)reader.GetValue(0));
                    }
                }
            }

            query = $@"SELECT name FROM ""feedback""";

            name = new List<string>();

            using (var command = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
            {
                using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        name.Add((string)reader.GetValue(0));
                    }
                }
            }

            query = $@"SELECT entry1 FROM ""feedback""";

            entry1 = new List<string>();

            using (var command = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
            {
                using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        entry1.Add((string)reader.GetValue(0));
                    }
                }
            }

            query = $@"SELECT entry2 FROM ""feedback""";

            entry2 = new List<string>();

            using (var command = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
            {
                using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        entry2.Add((string)reader.GetValue(0));
                    }
                }
            }

            query = $@"SELECT entry3 FROM ""feedback""";

            entry3 = new List<string>();

            using (var command = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
            {
                using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        entry3.Add((string)reader.GetValue(0));
                    }
                }
            }

            query = $@"SELECT entry4 FROM ""feedback""";

            entry4 = new List<string>();

            using (var command = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
            {
                using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        entry4.Add((string)reader.GetValue(0));
                    }
                }
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < max; i++)
            {
                yield return new Entries(id[i], date[i], name[i], entry1[i], entry2[i], entry3[i], entry4[i]);
            }

            conn.Close();
        }
```

Sorting them:

```
        private static List<Entries> SortEntries(SqlConnection conn)
        {
            var entries = new List<Entries>();

            foreach (var element in GetAllElementsClass(conn))
            {
                entries.Add(element);
            }

            entries = entries.OrderBy(x => x.Name).ToList();

            return entries;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The class you want to sort on (the list in this case) needs to implement the IComparer interface. Then the OrderBy operator calls IComparer.Compare to determine the sort sequence.

[IComparer.Compare](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.icomparer.compare?view=netcore-3.1)

So you need to create a class that extends List and implements IComparer. Inside this class' Compare method you can do whatever is necessary to determine which list is greater (based on some value within the list for example). Your dictionary will then take this new class as the second type.